# Backface visibility for Blender exported JSON files

Tags: export, normals, three.js, blend4web, webgl

When I export a model from Blender to three.js, it loads fine on the webpage. faces are visible only when I look at them from the direction of its normal and not from the other side. Is there a way to get the visibility of these faces from the back side / opposite side as well?

Edit 1:

I tried using bpy.context.object.active_material.THREE_double_sided = True and that did not work. I also added .doubleSided = true in the html. Still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

In Blend4Web you can do it by disabling **Backface Culling** https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/materials.html#rendering-properties

Answer (score -1):

material.doubleSided = True seems obsolete.

I Found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061271/three-jsonloader-double-sided-texture-png